# Radio Button not working well

Tags: laravel

I create a radio button with yes/no value. when choose yes then a text field is required and it working good. but when I choose no then text field is hide but the save button not working.
script code:

```
<script>
    $('input[name="master_study"]').click(function(e){
        if(e.target.value == 1){
            $('#university_name').show();
        }else{
            $('#university_name').hide();
        }
    });
     $('#university_name').hide();
</script>
```

and it is  my create.blade.php code:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'JobController@store','files'=>true]) !!}
 <div class="input-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="form-control" style="padding-top:2px;">
        {!! Form::label('master_study','Are you studying at a master level? ',['class'=>'input-group-inline']) !!}
        &emsp; &emsp;  &emsp;
        {!! Form::radio('master_study','1') !!} Yes
        &emsp; &emsp;  &emsp;
        {!! Form::label('university_name','If yes, Which university ? ') !!}
        {!! Form::text('university_name',null,['placeholder'=>'Name Of University', 'required']) !!}
        &emsp; &emsp;
        {!! Form::radio('master_study','0') !!} No
        &emsp; &emsp;

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
        {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary col-sm-4']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

it is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->jobs()->create($request->all());
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the text field to be "required". This will be true even if it's hidden. A possible solution might be something like this (I didn't test it, but you get the idea).

```
<script>
    $('input[name="master_study"]').click(function(e){
        if(e.target.value == 1){
            $('#university_name').attr('required', 'required');
            $('#university_name').show();

        }else{
           $('#university_name').removeAttr('required');​​​​​    
           $('#university_name').hide();
        }
    });
     $('#university_name').hide();
</script>
```

If the text field is hidden when you first show the form, make sure you remove the required attribute from the blade.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:

```
$this->validate($request,[

            'university_name' => 'required_if:master_study,==,1|nullable|string', 
         ]);
```